# "The product of convolution $(f\star g)$ is a commutative operation", doubt on proof

Tags: calculus

I started studying the "product of convolution" of two functions $f;g$ which is defined as $(f\star g)(t):=\int_{0^{-}}^{t^{+}}f(s)g(t-s)ds$. I understood that $f\star g$ is linear, as it is an integral, but I'm stuck on the simple prof that $(f\star g)=(g\star f)$. In fact: $(f\star g)(t):=\int_{0^{-}}^{t^{+}}f(s)g(t-s)ds$ and imposing the change of variable $(t-s)=u$ we get $s=0^{-}\rightarrow u=t^{+}$ and $s=t^{+}\rightarrow u=0^{-}$ which tells us $(f\star g)(t)=\int_{t^{+}}^{0^{-}}g(u)f(t-u)du=-(g\star f)(t)$ which tells  not commutativity of the operation $\star$. Where did I go wrong ?

Comment: Did you forget that $ds=-du$?

Comment: Yes, I forgot that and it was very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to handle the differential. Since $s$ is the variable in the original integral,
$$
u = t-s \implies \mathrm{d}u = - \mathrm{d}s
$$
so
$$
\int_{0^-}^{t^+} f(s) g(t-s) \, \mathrm{d} s
= -\int_{t^+}^{0^-} f(t-u) g(u) \, \mathrm{d} u
$$
The property that $\int_a^b h(x) \, \mathrm{d}x = -\int_b^a h(x) \, \mathrm{d}x$ allows us to conclude.